# Setting an autolayout NSSplitView initial position

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have an NSSplitView view which is backed by autolayout, and this works well. However I need to be able to set the initial split position in code (as it will be restored from a preference).

I can't quite figure out how to make this work. Prior to El Capitan, setting the frame width appeared to work but I realise this was circumventing the rules of autolayout so that isn't an option. Not using autolayout isn't really an option either. I need to set this when the view is being loaded so presumably there's a way to specify the same width as when setting the width in XCode but I can't work out how.

Any ideas? Pointers? Or is this impossible? I'd rather not have to switch to another NSSplitView variant if I can avoid it but will do if that's the only possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the constraints allow it, the split view's divider position should remain how it was set in the NIB.

You can set an `autosaveName` for a split view. If you set that, then the split view will save its divider position(s) in the preferences when it is adjusted at run time. On subsequent loads, it should restore its divider position(s) to whatever was saved.

Finally, you can use `-setPosition:ofDividerAtIndex:` to set it programmatically at any time, including in your `-viewDidLoad` or `-windowDidLoad` method.

Comment: I've never seen autosaveName work for NSSplitView for me, even when setting an identifier. I've seen comments elsewhere implying that it is broken.

Comment: I've just built a test project that uses a split view's `autosaveName` and it works just fine. Xcode 6.2, OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: Is that with autolayout? I'm using 10.11 and XCode 7 if that is relevant. From what I can see, the positions are being saved to the preferences file correctly but when the application is restarted, the saved positions are not being applied and are overwritten in the preferences with different ones.

Comment: Yes, it's with auto layout. I suspect you have constraint priorities that are pulling the divider away from its initial position. It's certainly possible there are bugs, such as the holding priority not kicking in early enough or something. In my case, each subview had a label which had fixed constraints to the top and left but greater-than-or-equal-to inequalities to the right and bottom. So there's absolutely no "pull" on the divider. It's simple enough to test yourself.

Comment: I just tested setting the trailing constraints to equals. That means the split view's holding priority is in competition with the label's content-hugging priority. So, I set the holding priority to be higher than the content-hugging priority. The `autosaveName` continued to work.